# What am i doing wrong with passenger/sinatra/apache....?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger, rack

I've never deployed an app before and now i cant get it to show up on my domain.com

my server is liquidweb, and it has apache2

I did `gem install passenger`

I ran `passenger-install-apache2-module` and everything installed correctly.

I logged in as root and added the following to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

I also added this, but this (ill paste it below) is where I'm confused. on the part below, is the path for the virtual host supposed to be relative to ROOT or the actual domain root. for example the absolute root the path to my app public directory is `/home/why/app/public` ... but from the account root its just `/app/public` im not sure which one to put. Furthermore, does it have to go in public_html? right now I put the app folder in just the root of the domain, not in public_html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /home/why/app/public
    <Directory /home/why/app/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When i visit domain.org, it just shows the default page...

```
Index of /
Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.11 Server at www.domain.org Port 80
```

Do i need to do anything else?? everyone says this is really easy, it simply wont load. Also, all the changes i made to httpd.conf i restarted apache, to no avail still.

I'm using sinatra. Heres my config.ru. the commented out portion is the local version of my config.ru which works fine if i run `rackup config.ru`:

```
#require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/main"
#run Sinatra::Application

require 'sinatra'

Sinatra::Application.default_options.merge!(
  :run => false,
  :env => ENV['RACK_ENV']
)

require 'main'
run Sinatra.application
```

Not sure what else there is to do... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was because i was using cpanel/whm and I have to do a few extra steps accessing a *.conf include.. http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/editing-virtualhost-settings-in-whm-cpanel/

this is what had to go in *.conf in the userdata folder

```
DocumentRoot /home/why/app/public
  <Directory /home/why/app/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
```